# Grandeur Cloud "signature invalid" error after apollo.init()

Tags: javascript, rest, iot, serverless

I downloaded Grandeur Cloud's datastore example from their github (https://github.com/grandeurtech/examples/tree/master/Datastore) and replaced the API key with my project's key, created a signature key/token pair and passed those to `apollo.init()`, but it's giving me a signature invalid error.

Is there something I'm missing here?

My JS file:
[Initializing Apollo with API key, signature key and token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfoxc.png)

```js
/**
 * @file main.js - Handles the working of our web app.
 * 
 * @requires apollo.js
*/

/** Initializing the SDK and getting reference to our project */
var apolloProject = apollo.init(
  "grandeurkcqeuvyy1ged01yjbl2pejkr",
  "kd4k3nv23wlh01vc7s8v36zh",
  "eyJ0b2tlbiI6ImV5SmhiR2NpT2lKSVV6STFOaUlzSW5SNWNDSTZJa3BYVkNKOS5leUpwWkNJNkltRmpZMlZ6YzJ0a05Hc3pibll5TTNkc2FEQXhkbU0zY3poMk16WjZhQ0lzSW5SNWNHVWlPaUpoWTJObGMzTWlMQ0pwWVhRaU9qRTFPVFU0TlRjd09EQjkuMndmNmlrQnNIOG0tSHh2QWhWcGloLXZFaDQ2SW9Jc2tZblZzTU13a1VXSSJ9"
);
```

This is the error I'm receiving in my console window:

[The error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpM4i.png)

What do you think would be the cause of such an error?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could cut and paste your code into the question instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your ACCESS-KEY is invalid. Like it is typically 30 character long, prefixed by keyword `access`. You can verify your key or generate a new one by visiting `security section` of [settings](https://cloud.grandeur.tech/settings) page.

To generate new security key/token pair, simply follow the following steps (ref: [hello world](https://www.hackster.io/grandeur/hello-world-with-grandeur-cloud-48e065#toc-step-2--get-started-on-web-1) tutorial & [docs](https://github.com/grandeurtech/grandeurcloud-js-sdk#init))

1. Go to security section of [settings](https://cloud.grandeur.tech/settings) page
2. Click on `Generate Access Credential` button
3. Enter a name in the input
4. Copy your access key and token (token won't be visible after closing the dialog)

Plus, as you have included your token & key in the screenshot so please do consider that

> It is highly recommended that please don't share your security credential, particularly the access key because it is used by the SDK to sign your request and never gets transferred over the wire. By using your security credential, a malicious user can pose to be you and send request to Grandeur Cloud on your behalf.

Finally, also make sure that you have whitelisted your domain. Otherwise you won't be able to make request to the server (ref: [docs](https://github.com/grandeurtech/grandeurcloud-js-sdk#get-started)).

I hope it will solve your issue, or otherwise you can comment under this post. You can also join the official [slack](https://grandeur.tech/slack) community to have a direct conversation with the developers.

Comment: I was removing the **access** part of the signature key ‍♂️ I thought that's just an extra string purposed to identify the string as an access key. Since you said its 30 characters long, I checked it again.

Now it's working correctly thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: Glad to help. Please feel free to reach out.